# Unit tests related to Time fail on bitrise

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, datetime, android-unit-testing

I have a unit test which passes locally on the machine, but on bitrise it fails. Unit test has time in it.

```
@Test
fun `If time is later than now in hours, then show in hours`() = runTest {
    clock.setInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(1686755085)) //Wed 14 Jun 16:05

    val first = chargeTileInteractor12.observe().first()

    assertEquals("in 3 hours", first.nextSessionDateText)
}
```

on bitrise unit test failed with error `org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<in [3] hours> but was:<in [4] hours>`

function that it is calling

```
    fun getNextSessionDateText(
        clock: Clock,
        targetDaySeconds: Int,
        timeZoneId: ZoneId
    ): String {
        val date = LocalDateTime.now(clock)
        val nowDaySeconds = date.toLocalTime().toSecondOfDay()
        return if (targetDaySeconds >= nowDaySeconds) {
            val newSeconds = targetDaySeconds - nowDaySeconds
            val newMinutes = secondsToMinutes(newSeconds.toLong())
            val newHours = minutesToHoursRounded(newMinutes)
            if (newHours > 0) {
                "in $newHours hours"
            } else if (newMinutes > 0) {
                "in $newMinutes minutes"
            } else {
                "in $newSeconds seconds"
            }
        } else {
            val newPastSeconds = nowToMidnightSeconds(timeZoneId) + targetDaySeconds
            val newPastMinutes = secondsToMinutes(newPastSeconds)
            val newPastHours = minutesToHoursRounded(newPastMinutes)
            if (newPastHours > 0) {
                "in $newPastHours hours"
            } else if (newPastMinutes > 0) {
                "in $newPastMinutes minutes"
            } else {
                "in $newPastSeconds seconds"
            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to get this to work please

Thanks
R